# I do something wrong with 'for'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram

I have optimized "if" statement. But I don't understand why my code doesn't work.
Following code must count how many rows in spreadsheet, and by command from "/1" to "/max" send a message with data from row.

```
  var postInfo = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i; i < postInfo.length; i++){
     if(msg.text == '/'[i])
     {
        var post = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 13).getValues()[0];
        var message = post[0];
     }
  }


if (msg.text == '/1') 
      { 
        var post = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 13).getValues()[0];
        var message = post[0];
      }
      if (msg.text == '/2') 
      { 
        var post = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, 13).getValues()[0];
        var message = post[0];
      }
      if (msg.text == '/3') 
      { 
        var post = sheet.getRange(4, 1, 1, 13).getValues()[0];
        var message = post[0];
      }

      ........

      if (msg.text == '/14') 
      { 
        var post = sheet.getRange(15, 1, 1, 13).getValues()[0];
        var message = post[0];
      }

      if (msg.text == '/all') 
      { 
        var post = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 15, 1).getValues()[0];
        var message = post[0];
      }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here `if(msg.text == '/'[i])`?

Comment: ... and what are you trying to do, if the above condition passes? I mean assigning a value to a variable in a loop gives you the last value only after the loop.

Comment: Try `for(var i = 0; i < postInfo.length; i++){` instead.

Comment: @brk I want to set msg.text to /i, it means when someone write in chat, for example "/1" - spreadsheet send to him 1st row.

Comment: @Teemu I want to loop count how many rows in my document, and after, when I will send command - like "/1", telegram bot will answer me with info from spreadsheet.

Comment: @ross sorry, what a difference between my loop and yours?

Comment: guys its my first project, and Im trying to do best, but my knowlenge not so well

Comment: Read about the javascript bracket operator and strings. You probably wanted string concatenation...

Comment: @tehhowch thank you for advice, I really forgot about concatenation.

Comment: @AlekseyMityukov note that while this will work for a time, you might want to look at getting the number straight from your input e.g. via regex; `msg.text.match(/\/(\d+)/)[1]`, and using that rather than a for-loop making potentially hundreds or thousands of comparisons